# how to disable rtl when phone language changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

i created an app in react-native ,when the phone language is En every thing goes fine but when i change the phone language the UI crashes and everything is backward
i am using

```
"react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.5",
```

Answer (score 17):

You should disable rtl view in your app

Put this code in app.js:-

```
const ReactNative = require('react-native');
try {
  ReactNative.I18nManager.allowRTL(false);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: In index.js not App.js ::
import {AppRegistry, I18nManager} from 'react-native';
I18nManager.allowRTL(false);
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);

Answer (score 7):

`I18nManager.allowRTL(false);` didn't work on first time when I opened application but it did the next times that I opened application. Instead I made these changes in `MainApplication.java` and it works completely fine:

```
import com.facebook.react.modules.i18nmanager.I18nUtil;
....
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // FORCE LTR
    I18nUtil sharedI18nUtilInstance = I18nUtil.getInstance();
    sharedI18nUtilInstance.allowRTL(getApplicationContext(), false);
    .....
}
.....
```

[Resource](https://newbedev.com/rtl-is-forced-in-rtl-devices)

Answer (score 6):

Similar to @Roozbeh but you can just do this:

```
import { I18nManager} from 'react-native';
```

then

```
 try { 
    I18nManager.allowRTL(false);
} 
catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```